# Kamailio - WebSocket - Setup

Tags: kamailio

I am an web developer and want to create a WEBRTC application.  My knowledge level in SIP is beginner.  I want my application to talk to kamailio and in process of setting up kamailio by following the below articles.

http://nil.uniza.sk/sip/kamailio/configuring-kamailio-4x-websocket
http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.3.x/modules/websocket.html

I was able to connect (using try.jssp.net) to kamailio as multiple clients for initial setup but unable to call from one browser client to another client.  Below is the log message that I see in the kamailio server.

I see this error message multiple times logged

```
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25063]: INFO: <core> [parser/parse_fline.c:146]: parse_first_line(): ERROR:parse_first_line: method not followed by SP
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25063]: ERROR: <core> [parser/parse_fline.c:243]: parse_first_line(): parse_first_line: bad message (offset: 0)
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25063]: DEBUG: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:619]: parse_msg(): parse_msg: invalid message
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25063]: ERROR: <core> [parser/msg_parser.c:705]: parse_msg(): ERROR: parse_msg: message=<#001#020#002#021#037?#037?#012^cP#012^cP#001#020#002#026?A#037?H#0229w>
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25063]: ERROR: <core> [receive.c:149]: receive_msg(): core parsing of SIP message failed (10.94.99.80:8088/1)
```

and also found this in the log

```
DEBUG: <core> [dset.c:774]: uri_add_rcv_alias(): encoded <sip:d63im5st@avltu6trdhg0.invalid;transport=ws;ob> => [sip:d63im5st@avltu6trdhg0.invalid;transport=ws;ob;alias=172.18.57.119~60481~5]
Aug  9 20:27:33 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25074]: DEBUG: nathelper [nathelper.c:965]: add_contact_alias_0_f(): contact uri host is not an ip address
Aug  9 20:27:33 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25074]: ERROR: nathelper [nathelper.c:977]: add_contact_alias_0_f(): you can't call add_contact_alias twice, check your config!
Aug  9 20:27:33 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25074]: ERROR: <script>: Error aliasing contact <<sip:d63im5st@avltu6trdhg0.invalid;transport=ws;ob>>
```

Additional log info

```
Aug  9 20:27:10 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25072]: DEBUG: websocket [ws_frame.c:661]: ws_frame_receive(): Rx SIP message:#012REGISTER sip:ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com SIP/2.0#015#012Via: SIP/2.0/WS avltu6trdhg0.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6572200#015#012Max-Forwards: 69#015#012To: <sip:agent01@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>#015#012From: "agent01" <sip:agent01@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>;tag=68gqn060sb#015#012Call-ID: 22oik6ujj2bfjuuauasgdq#015#012CSeq: 1 REGISTER#015#012Contact: <sip:d63im5st@avltu6trdhg0.invalid;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:74809558-6d30-42c3-afbd-072d5d0ad5ab>";expires=600#015#012Expires: 600#015#012Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER#015#012Supported: path,gruu,outbound#015#012User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.3#015#012Content-Length: 0#015#012#015#012
Aug  9 20:27:15 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25073]: DEBUG: websocket [ws_frame.c:661]: ws_frame_receive(): Rx SIP message:#012REGISTER sip:ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com SIP/2.0#015#012Via: SIP/2.0/WS egvf3nqhdl35.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK4737687#015#012Max-Forwards: 69#015#012To: <sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>#015#012From: "agent02" <sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>;tag=8dldgic783#015#012Call-ID: v4rim0ku5dtqrtqkcgv0an#015#012CSeq: 1 REGISTER#015#012Contact: <sip:bh9ao5ab@egvf3nqhdl35.invalid;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:f593c0a4-0984-46a0-8f3e-a231fb4d1713>";expires=600#015#012Expires: 600#015#012Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER#015#012Supported: path,gruu,outbound#015#012User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.3#015#012Content-Length: 0#015#012#015#012
Aug  9 20:27:33 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25074]: DEBUG: websocket [ws_frame.c:661]: ws_frame_receive(): Rx SIP message:#012INVITE sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com SIP/2.0#015#012Via: SIP/2.0/WS avltu6trdhg0.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9231290#015#012Max-Forwards: 69#015#012To: <sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>#015#012From: "agent01" <sip:agent01@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>;tag=jngmrtvvec#015#012Call-ID: s1fdqticqc31ru6p5cfs#015#012CSeq: 9973 INVITE#015#012X-Can-Renegotiate: true#015#012Contact: <sip:d63im5st@avltu6trdhg0.invalid;transport=ws;ob>#015#012Content-Type: application/sdp#015#012Session-Expires: 90#015#012Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER#015#012Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound#015#012User-Agent: JsSIP 0.7.3#015#012Content-Length: 3876#015#012#015#012v=0#015#012o=- 7098982196661734965 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1#015#012s=-#015#012t=0 0#015#012a=group:BUNDLE audio video#015#012a=msid-semantic: WMS XynF2020ZZYtShWgfoYkS23q5sgbtcquUl0s#015#012m=audio 56249 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126#015#012c=IN IP4 172.18.57.119#015#012a=rtcp:54672 IN IP4 172.18.57.119#015#012a=candidate:2390899093 1 udp 2122260223 172.18.57.119 56249 typ host generation 0#015#012a=candidate:1221703924 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.0.105 60197 typ host generation 0#015#012a=candidate:2390899093 2 udp 2122260222 172.18.57.119 54672 typ host generation 0#015#012a=candidate:1221703924 2 udp 2122194686 192.168.0.105 54423 typ host generation 0#015#012a=candidate:3221341541 1 tcp 1518280447 172.18.57.119 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0#015#012a=candidate:106054660 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.0.105 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0#015#012a=candidate:3221341541 2 tcp 1518280446 172.18.57.119 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0#015#012a=candidate:106054660 2 tcp 1518214910 192.168.0.105 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0#015#012a=ice-ufrag:Las7oILW40BIM8zF#015#012a=ice-pwd:A3ewod5vG57HcA/JvnAaRGWV#015#012a=fingerprint:sha-256 31:22:C5:67:B6:CB:D0:66:7D:E4
Aug  9 20:27:33 ip-10-94-99-80 /usr/sbin/kamailio[25074]: DEBUG: websocket [ws_frame.c:661]: ws_frame_receive(): Rx SIP message:#012ACK sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com SIP/2.0#015#012Via: SIP/2.0/WS avltu6trdhg0.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9231290#015#012To: <sip:agent02@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>;tag=5f994d94abde79a17171e171202b0e42.d13e#015#012From: "agent01" <sip:agent01@ip-10-94-99-80.customdomain.com>;tag=jngmrtvvec#015#012Call-ID: s1fdqticqc31ru6p5cfs#015#012CSeq: 9973 ACK#015#012Content-Length: 0#015#012#015#012
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Error message about aliasing contact suggest that the config is broken. Load debugger module and enable cfg trace feature to see what actions are executed in the config file in order to see where the routing of INVITE gets blocked.

Comment: Thank You for the response,voice and video are fixed but for messaging I get "408 request timeout" buf=#012?~#001?SIP/2.0 408 Request Timeout#015#012Via: SIP/2.0/WS 0hiss3di50je.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK1367902;rport=50795;received=10.114.225.202#015#012To: <sip:abc123@test.com>;tag=b44d120c617c843b219e52eae8b5e9ff-fe36#015#012From: "ZXC" <sip:zxc936@test.com:8088>;tag=e27o1jpb6r#015#012Call-ID: vmg90mrsm91hmj681blh#015#012CSeq: 7658 MESSAGE#015#012Server: kamailio (4.4.0-dev2 (x86_64/linux))#015#012Content-Length: 0#015#012#015#012  Any Thoughts?

Comment: What what log messages are printed when routing the MESSAGE request, set debug=3 in kamailio.cfg.

Comment: will you provide the kamailio.cfg so we can trace it?

Answer (score 0):

So you should check your kamailio.cfg, I think config is broken.

And maybe you want to use Asterisk or Freeswitch for WebRTC and PBX. You can find the Kamailio and Freeswitch integration tutorial here:

http://kb.asipto.com/freeswitch:kamailio-3.1.x-freeswitch-1.0.6d-sbc

It will be good choice using Kamailio as routing and registar server. Generally we use Freeswitch or Asterisk as media server for these kind of operations.

Please feel free ask me any questions.